# Confirming a delete using AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, database, android-alertdialog, confirm

So I'm trying to get AlertDialog to confirm a click on a 'delete from database' button. Been trying for a fairly long time and can't get a working model. My current code is as follows.

At top of class a boolean

```
private static boolean dialogResult;
```

A method to display dialogs

```
private void showErrorDialog(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Activity.setDialogResult(true);
                dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Activity.setDialogResult(false);
                dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

where the setDialogResult(bool) just sets the aforementioned class variable.

when the 'delete' button is pressed this code executes:

```
setDialogResult(false);
//Find which list is to be deleted
        RadioButton selectedBtn=(RadioButton)findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        String currentSelectedListName=selectedBtn.getText().toString();

            if(!currentSelectedListName.equals("All")){//check if the list is the default
                showErrorDialog("","Delete: "+currentSelectedListName+" ?");
                if(dialogResult){
                    mDbHelper.deleteFGList(currentSelectedListName);
                    this.populateRadioGroupFromDb();
                }
            }  else{//if it is the default (That is, the name of the list is "All") tell user of error
                showErrorDialog("Delete Error","The default list cannot be deleted");
            }
        //}
```

Appreciate the help!

Edit: sorry, forgot to mention the error I was having. When you hit OK in the alert dialog it does not delete the item from the database. Somehow it is skipping over that boolean check. You can see I set the value of the boolean to false at the beginning of that code snippet. If it is deleted then you press the 'delete' button, ok button in the dialog, and then nothing happens. If you press the 'delete' button again then this new selection will be deleted automatically without dialog checking. Basically, those onClick methods are messed up, and I was hoping there was a better way to do it. I've read something about using interfaces?

So it seems people have been suggesting this approach

```
if(!currentSelectedListName.equals("All")){//check if the list is the default
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("")
                    .setMessage("Delete: "+currentSelectedListName+" ?")
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                mDbHelper.deleteFGList(currentSelectedListName);
                                Activity.populateRadioGroupFromDb();
                            }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,null);
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }  else{//if it is the default (That is, the name of the list is "All") tell user of error
                showErrorDialog("Delete Error","The default list cannot be deleted");
            }
```

Problem is that eclipse gives compile errors on

```
mDbHelper.deleteFGList(currentSelectedListName);
Activity.populateRadioGroupFromDb();
```

1.Cannot refer to a non-final variable currentSelectedListName inside an inner class defined in a different 
     method
2.Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method populateRadioGroupFromDb() from the type MyFGCardsActivity

Is this the advocated approach or am  I misunderstanding?

Comment: What problem are you facing ? is the dialog shown ?

Answer (score 1):

Android dialogs are not modal by design. That is, they will not block execution of your code until dismissed but `show()` will return immediately. Therefore, when you write code like this:

```
showErrorDialog("","Delete: "+currentSelectedListName+" ?");
if(dialogResult){
```

the `dialogResult` is not yet available.

Now you mention something about "interfaces" and that's a part of the solution. You should assign callbacks e.g. to positive and negative buttons that do what you want. These callbacks are implemented in terms of Java interfaces. You actually already have such callback interfaces in place already: `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`.

So put whatever code that should run on positive click in the listener on the positive button e.g. the delete code, and put whatever code that should run on negative click in that corresponding listener e.g. nothing. And get rid of the `dialogResult` variable and possibly any tutorials that promote such coding style (using static class vars for local state information).

Calling `dismiss()` in the `onClick()` listener here is redundant: when you assign the listeners like this, the dialog will be already be dismissed when your listener runs.

Comment: I agree the dialogResult method is a bad approach, just the best I could find. I edit my original post, is that what you meant? I don't have much experience creating usable interfaces so now really sure how I would go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

Call this two line in setPositiveButton

```
mDbHelper.deleteFGList(currentSelectedListName);
this.populateRadioGroupFromDb();
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the OnClick method in setPositiveButton is considered to be in a different class, so currentSelectedListName is not passed and ActivityClass.populateRadioGroupFromDb(); did not work due to static, nonstatic issues. Tried this one already